# How to get the activity or class calling the android soft keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-intent, input, keyboard

I am trying to create a custom android keyboard and i want to get the app that called the input method from the keyboard class. 
Secondly i wish to use it to send a picture to the app via intent. so is there a way i can achieve this?